# How do you solve $\sin 2x-\cos x>0$ for all $x$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I'm not sure what to do about the inequality, I got to:

$\sin 2x-\cos x>0$

$2\sin x\cos x-\cos x>0$

$\cos x(2\sin x-1)>0$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Either:$$\cos(x)>0,~2\sin(x)-1>0$$or$$\cos(x)<0,~2\sin(x)-1<0$$

Comment: Why am I also solving for <0?

Comment: @user66590 its a product and if both are negative then the product is positive $( -*-=+)$

Comment: If $a$ is negative and $b$ is negative, then $ab$ is positive, which is what you are solving for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \times y > 0$, then you know that one of two things is true: Either $x > 0$ and $y > 0$, or $x < 0$ and $y < 0$. Therefore, you consider two cases:

1. $\cos x > 0$ and $2\sin x - 1 > 0$; or
2. $\cos x < 0$ and $2\sin x - 1 < 0$.

Solve the two separately, and the union of the two solution sets is your final solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos x>0\;\text{ and }\;\sin x >\frac12 \iff \frac\pi6<x<\frac\pi2 \pmod{2\pi},$$
$$\cos x<0\;\text{ and }\;\sin x <\frac12 \iff \frac{7\pi}6<x<\frac{3\pi}2 \pmod{2\pi}.$$